# Como trabalhar com 2 json diferentes para criar um padrão em c#

Tags: c#, json

Estou montando uma solução de rastreio que trabalha com duas couriers diferentes, e cada uma delas responde com um json diferente ao ser consultada.

No meu caso eu tenho a resposta da courier 1 como:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "statusRetorno": "00",
    "hawbs": [
      {
        "codigoCartao": "código de rastreio",
        "hawbId": "código interno da courier1",
        "dtCol": "04/01/2024 04:43:24.653",
        "dtPos": null,
        "dtSla": "31/01/2024 23:59:59.000",
        "contrato": 0001,
        "baixa": [],
        "historico": [
          {
            "ocorrencia": "22/01/2024 14:02:52.928",
            "eventoId": "1400",
            "evento": "Postado - logistica iniciada",
            "arCorreios": "",
            "frq": "VMA",
            "local": "PORTO ALEGRE",
            "situacao": null,
            "situacaoId": null
          },
          {
            "ocorrencia": "23/01/2024 08:44:59.430",
            "eventoId": "4100",
            "evento": "Entrega em andamento (na rua)",
            "arCorreios": "",
            "frq": "VMA",
            "local": "PORTO ALEGRE",
            "situacao": null,
            "situacaoId": null
          }          
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "error": null
}
```

Já a segunda courier eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "previsaoEntrega": "2024-01-17T05:20:45.000Z",
      "remessa": null,
      "pedido": "pedido",
      "pedido2": "pedido2",
      "dataColeta": "2024-01-12T05:20:45.640Z",
      "dataBaixa": "2024-01-16T12:17:54.266Z",
      "recebedor": null,
      "docRecebedor": null,
      "numeroPostagem": "",
      "postagem": false,
      "logradouro": null,
      "numero": null,
      "complemento": null,
      "bairro": null,
      "cidade": null,
      "uf": null,
      "cep": 0,
      "tentativasEntrega": 0,
      "teveAlteracaoEndereco": false,
      "ras": [
        {
          "codigo": codigo1,
          "det": {
            "dataHoraOcorrencia": "2024-01-10T19:02:07.623Z",
            "dataHoraCadastroLancamento": "2024-01-10T19:02:07.623Z",
            "ocorrencia": {
              "codigo": 1,
              "descricao": "Arquivo processado",
              "configRetornoCliente": {
                "descricao": "Arquivo processado",
                "codigoCli": "1",
                "situacaoCodigo": null,
                "situacaoDescricao": "Arquivo processado"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "codigo": 1723246250,
          "det": {
            "dataHoraOcorrencia": "2024-01-12T05:20:45.641Z",
            "dataHoraCadastroLancamento": "2024-01-12T05:20:45.641Z",
            "ocorrencia": {
              "codigo": 2,
              "descricao": "Remessa conciliada",
              "configRetornoCliente": {
                "descricao": "Remessa conciliada",
                "codigoCli": "2",
                "situacaoCodigo": null,
                "situacaoDescricao": "Remessa conciliada"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "parentescoFinal": null,
      "enderecoAlterado": null
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

O que eu estou tentando fazer é colocar somente o que importa da courier 1 e 2 num 3º objeto que  será +- assim:

```
public class PadraoRastreioModel
{
    public string Rastreio { get; set; }
    public string DataColeta { get; set; }
    public string DataPostagem { get; set; }
    public string DataBaixa { get; set; }
    public string Recebedor { get; set; }
    public List<Hist> Historico { get; set; }
}
    
public class Hist
{
    public string DataOcorrencia { get; set; }
    public string DescritivoOcorrencia { get; set; }
}
```

Sobre o campo `Rastreio`:

- Receber o valor do `codigoCartao` do primeiro JSON ou então, receber o valor do `pedido` do segundo JSON, dependendo do RASTREIO que eu for usar.

Sobre os campos DataColeta, DataPostagem, DataBaixa e Recebedor:

- Eles tem equivalente nos dois JSON.

Sobre a lista `Hist` deve receber no campo:

- `DataOcorrencia` o valor de `ocorrencia do primeiro JSON ou` dataocorrencia` do segundo JSON,
- `DescritivoOcorrencia` receberá `evento` do primeiro JSON ou `descricao` do segundo JSON.

O meu problema é que não estou conseguindo acessar os valores que preciso depois fazer um deserialize do json que recebo na aplicação.

Estou usando o RestSharp pra fazer as chamadas e tenho a seguinte classe

```
public async virtual Task<ResponseModel> Post<TOut>(RequestModel Resource)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new RestClient(this.baseAddress))
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(Resource.Uri, Method.Post);

            foreach(var head in Resource.Headers)
            {
                request.AddHeader(head.Key, head.Value);
            }

            foreach(var head in Resource.Content)
            {
                request.AddHeader(head.Key, head.Value);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Resource.Body))
            {
                request.AddJsonBody(Resource.Body);
            }

            var response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TOut>(response.Content);
                return new ResponseModel(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return new ResponseModel((int)response.StatusCode, "Erro ao realizar solicitação", response.Content);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ResponseModel((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

a resposta chega certinho... mas preciso "padronizar" ela naquela classe PadraoRastreioModel.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode criar duas classes/DTOs de cada COURIER, e fazer um var `firstCourierResponse =                 
 JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CLasse/DTOCourier1>(response);` assim você terá um objeto acessável da resposta da API, e você fazer a atribuição de cada dado que você queira, em um objeto seu que terá o merge das responses.

Comment: E você deveria nos trazer mais informações, como Data Coleta do primeiro JSON, e Data Coleta do segundo JSON, sempre serão iguais? Quando for nulo, fazer o que? Traga mais detalhes para que haja mais chance de te ajudarem.

Comment: Por exemplo, este seu trecho "A lista Histórico deve receber no campo DataOcorrencia o valor de "ocorrencia" da courier1 ou "dataocorrencia" da courier2, DescritivoOcorrencia receberá "evento" da courier 1 ou "descricao" da courier 2.". Isso quer dizer que se ocorrencia do 1 for nula, a gente usa o 2?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Desculpe a demora aqui, mas a correria ta complicada.

Quanto a parte de criar a classe/DTO, eu tentei e na hora que coloco o meu response, está aparecendo que não é possível converter de objetc para string...


Já a questão de informações de Data Coleta, tanto do primeiro quanto do Segundo, elas podem ser nulas, e não serão simultâneas.
Eu faço a consulta com um numero de AR, tipo correios sabe? Então tenho o numero AB12345678XX, onde o XX me indica de que courier é... se for, por exemplo AB, é da courier 1, se for CD é da 2, mas pode ser nulo sim.

Comment: O mesmo caso se aplica para a questão da lista de histórico. Dependendo do rastreio colocado, o final indicará se é da courier 1 ou 2, podendo ser nulo, e não são concorrentes... se o rastreio cor da courier 1, usará o valor do "evento", se for da courier 2 usará "descrição" e em ambos os casos, poderá ser nulo caso não tenha nenhum histórico ainda (caso de rastreio recém aberto)

Comment: Opa... deu certo aqui com uma pequena correção na classe criada, só precisei mudar uma parte do meu response jogando ele para um .ToString()

Obrigado Vagner